# Why do character colors sometimes suddenly change?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I've seen this used in almost all of the episodes, where during a fight or a scene the colors of the characters will change almost immediately, almost to an inverted color scheme, or sometimes a more muted color scheme.

[In this scene](https://youtu.be/LRGMJahRaJc?t=11s), you'll notice that Josuke's Stand, Crazy Diamond, is normally colored blue/pink, yet during the fight switches to blue/green, while Killer Queen, who is normally Pink/Black/Gold, is switched to Gold/Black/Blue (body, gloves, skullpiece).

[In another fight, seen here](https://youtu.be/EZ14-5cJ73s?t=2m10s), not only does Josuke and Yoshikage change colors, but their stands change color to yet another different color, with Crazy Diamond turning blue/brown, and Kira Queen turning Blue/Green/Yellow.

Another example of Yoshikage and Josuke:

[image: Original]

[image: After]

Is there a specific reason for doing this technique?  Why has David Co "switched" the colors sometimes during a fight?

Comment: Only reason I can tell, is just sloppiness or pushing an episode out.  Some series have a lot of issues, while others have fewer.....how should I put it.....gaffes?

Comment: It's to convey emotion and atmosphere. Similar to HxH's Hisoka when he shows bloodlust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I know, Araki enjoys playing with various colour schemes, which is evident in multiple different colour versions of the characters in manga covers and coloured artwork, which the anime series has followed as it is a big 'part' of the look and feel of Jojo-series as a whole. For specific instances of colour, I guess it's mainly to enhance and add visual flavour to dramatic scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed in stardust crusaders at the start when we first see Kakyoin, he calls Jotaro "evil" and after Jotaro says "Evil?" they swap colors, making Kakyoin and Hierophant purple and Jotaro and Star platinum green.

It would almost be like Jotaro's the "loser" and the "evil one" until it turns around, making Kakyoin the "loser" and the "evil one".
Thus Jotaro saying "I may be deemed a punk but i know nauseating evil when i see one"

That is my theory about it. 
It might as well just be its own style of showing off cool colors but there may be a bigger meaning to it all.